# Error: LateInitializedState: flutter is showing state is not initialized error after switching themeMode

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I have an app and I built some helper widgets to be able to reuse.
so I created this `Button` Widget which can show a loading icon if pressed and the async request is not completed. This is working fine when the app is hot restarted but when I am changing anything in the app or switching theme it is throwing an error that says this:

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'btnState' has not been initialized
```

However, it is working fine when creating this same concept using `GetX` package for state management for the `busy` and `disabled` state of the `Button` Widget but it is not working when using the flutter native way.

I think when switching theme `GetX` re-initialize all the widgets in the widget tree but `StatefulWidget` does not initialize it.

If you want to see `GetX` approach you can see here [Flutter MVC Button Widget](https://github.com/thedevsbuddy/flutter_mvc/blob/085170298e9a504af6460f53d578a6d1c4a6b6f3/packages/basic_ui/lib/widgets/buttons/Button.dart)

Here is my `Button` Widget code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../helpers/ColorPalette.dart';
import '../helpers/TextStyl.dart';
import 'LoadingIcon.dart';

class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  late final _ButtonState btnState;

  final String label;
  final void Function(_ButtonState)? onTap;
  final bool outline;
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget? loadingIcon;
  final bool block;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final Color? color;
  final bool flat;

  Button({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    this.onTap,
    this.leading,
    this.loadingIcon,
    this.flat = false,
    this.backgroundColor = kcPrimary,
    this.color,
  })  : outline = false,
        block = false,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Button> createState() {
    btnState = _ButtonState();
    return btnState;
  }
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  bool isBusy = false;
  bool isDisabled = false;

  setBusy(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      isBusy = val;
    });
    return widget.btnState;
  }

  setDisabled(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      isDisabled = val;
    });
    return widget.btnState;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (!isBusy && !isDisabled) {
          widget.onTap!(widget.btnState);
        }
      },
      child: widget.block
          ? AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: !widget.outline
                  ? BoxDecoration(
                      color: !isDisabled ? widget.backgroundColor : widget.backgroundColor?.withOpacity(0.5),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!widget.flat ? 8 : 0),
                    )
                  : BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!widget.flat ? 8 : 0),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: !isDisabled ? widget.backgroundColor! : widget.backgroundColor!.withOpacity(0.5),
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
              child: !isBusy
                  ? Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        if (widget.leading != null) widget.leading!,
                        if (widget.leading != null) SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          widget.label,
                          style: TextStyl.button(context)?.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: !widget.outline ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.w400,
                            color: !widget.outline
                                ? widget.color != null
                                    ? widget.color
                                    : getContrastColor(widget.backgroundColor!)
                                : widget.backgroundColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : widget.loadingIcon != null
                      ? SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20, child: widget.loadingIcon)
                      : LoadingIcon(
                          color: !widget.outline
                              ? widget.color != null
                                  ? widget.color
                                  : getContrastColor(widget.backgroundColor!)
                              : widget.backgroundColor,
                          height: 16,
                        ),
            )
          : Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: !widget.outline
                      ? BoxDecoration(
                          color: !isDisabled ? widget.backgroundColor! : widget.backgroundColor!.withOpacity(0.5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!widget.flat ? 8 : 0),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: widget.backgroundColor!,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        )
                      : BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!widget.flat ? 8 : 0),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: widget.backgroundColor!,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                  child: !isBusy
                      ? Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            if (widget.leading != null) widget.leading!,
                            if (widget.leading != null) SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Text(
                              widget.label,
                              style: TextStyl.button(context)?.copyWith(
                                fontWeight: !widget.outline ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.w400,
                                color: !widget.outline
                                    ? widget.color != null
                                        ? widget.color
                                        : getContrastColor(widget.backgroundColor!)
                                    : widget.backgroundColor!,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      : widget.loadingIcon != null
                          ? SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20, child: widget.loadingIcon)
                          : LoadingIcon(
                              color: !widget.outline
                                  ? widget.color != null
                                      ? widget.color
                                      : getContrastColor(widget.backgroundColor!)
                                  : widget.backgroundColor!,
                              height: 16,
                            ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code where I used the `Button` Widget:

```dart
Button(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  label: "Test",
  onTap: (btn) async {
    btn.setBusy(true);
    await Future.delayed(2.seconds);
    btn.setBusy(false);
  },
),
```

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. in my case it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself trying to manually access/manipulate the private `_State` class of any `StatefulWidget` then its a sign that you need to find a better approach to whatever it is you're trying to do.

I would avoid stuff like this

```
 late final _ButtonState btnState; // this

...

 @override
  State<Button> createState() {
    btnState = _ButtonState(); // this
    return btnState;
  }

...

  final void Function(_ButtonState)? onTap; // using private state as arguments
```

If you want to do what that repo is doing with GetX in a native Flutter way then here's one way to approach it using [ValueNotifier](https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b)

If everything in the button depends on the status of an `isBusy` and `isDisabled` bool, then I'd create a custom class that `ValueNotifier` will sync to.

```
class ButtonStatus {
  ButtonStatus({required this.isBusy, required this.isDisabled});

  final bool isBusy;
  final bool isDisabled;
}
```

Then a static controller class with relevant methods with similar functionality to the `Getx` class in the repo in addition to the same thing you're currently passing in as a test.

```
class ButtonStatusController {
// status is what ValueNotifier listens to
  static ValueNotifier<ButtonStatus> status = ValueNotifier(
    ButtonStatus(isBusy: false, isDisabled: false),
  );

  // equivalent to the function you're passing in the button
  static Future<void> testFunction() async {
    final isDisabled = status.value.isDisabled;
    status.value = ButtonStatus(isBusy: true, isDisabled: isDisabled);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    status.value = ButtonStatus(isBusy: false, isDisabled: isDisabled);
  }

  // updating ButtonStatus
  static void updateButtonStatus(
      {required bool isBusy, required bool isDisabled}) {
    status.value = ButtonStatus(isBusy: isBusy, isDisabled: isDisabled);
  }
}
```

Then your `Button` gets wrapped in a `ValueListenableBuilder<ButtonStatus>` and can be stateless. It will rebuild based on changes to the `ButtonStatus` and the functionality won't be affected by any changes to the `Theme` of the app.

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final void Function() onTap;
  final bool outline;
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget? loadingIcon;
  final bool block;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final Color? color;
  final bool flat;

  Button({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.onTap,
    this.leading,
    this.loadingIcon,
    this.flat = false,
    this.backgroundColor = kcPrimary,
    this.color,
  })  : outline = false,
        block = false,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // wrapping in ValueListenableBuilder of type ButtonStatus
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ButtonStatus>(
      valueListenable: ButtonStatusController
          .status, // listening to any updates in the ButtonStatusController class
      builder: (_, status, __) => GestureDetector(
        // status here is what all the conditional builds in this widget now depend on
        onTap: () {
          if (!status.isBusy && !status.isDisabled) {
            onTap();
          }
        },
        child: block
            ? AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: !outline
                    ? BoxDecoration(
                        color: !status.isDisabled
                            ? backgroundColor
                            : backgroundColor?.withOpacity(0.5),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!flat ? 8 : 0),
                      )
                    : BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!flat ? 8 : 0),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: !status.isDisabled
                              ? backgroundColor!
                              : backgroundColor!.withOpacity(0.5),
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                child: !status.isBusy
                    ? Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          if (leading != null) leading!,
                          if (leading != null) SizedBox(width: 5),
                          Text(
                            label,
                            style: TextStyl.button(context)?.copyWith(
                              fontWeight:
                                  !outline ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.w400,
                              color: !outline
                                  ? color != null
                                      ? color
                                      : getContrastColor(backgroundColor!)
                                  : backgroundColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : loadingIcon != null
                        ? SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20, child: loadingIcon)
                        : LoadingIcon(
                            color: !outline
                                ? color != null
                                    ? color
                                    : getContrastColor(backgroundColor!)
                                : backgroundColor,
                            height: 16,
                          ),
              )
            : Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: !outline
                        ? BoxDecoration(
                            color: !status.isDisabled
                                ? backgroundColor!
                                : backgroundColor!.withOpacity(0.5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!flat ? 8 : 0),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: backgroundColor!,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                          )
                        : BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(!flat ? 8 : 0),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: backgroundColor!,
                              width: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                    child: !status.isBusy
                        ? Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              if (leading != null) leading!,
                              if (leading != null) SizedBox(width: 5),
                              Text(
                                label,
                                style: TextStyl.button(context)?.copyWith(
                                  fontWeight: !outline
                                      ? FontWeight.bold
                                      : FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: !outline
                                      ? color != null
                                          ? color
                                          : getContrastColor(backgroundColor!)
                                      : backgroundColor!,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        : loadingIcon != null
                            ? SizedBox(
                                height: 20, width: 20, child: loadingIcon)
                            : LoadingIcon(
                                color: !outline
                                    ? color != null
                                        ? color
                                        : getContrastColor(backgroundColor!)
                                    : backgroundColor!,
                                height: 16,
                              ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Besides that, I suggest reading up on refactoring widgets with large build methods because that one is a bit unruly. It could me made a lot easier to read by breaking it up into smaller `StatelessWidgets`.

Comment: It may work but I was just trying to make it easy but your code suggestion looks a bit complex which leads me to stick with the `GetX` approach. BTW that repository is mine which is using `GetX` but I was trying to make it with `StatefulWidget` which can be used by any other developer out there because everyone does not use `GetX`.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose complexity is subjective because that strikes me as more or less the same structure as the GetX solution with a controller class and a widget that rebuilds based on the variables in that class. Either way, I would argue that you're going beyond the intended functionality of the `StatefulWidget` with what you're attempting to do in your original post. So any state management solution would be preferable.